# Is there dedicated hardware currently on sale?

Tags: dapps, hardware

Wondering if there is anyone that sells hardware dedicated to Ethereum or some Dapp in particular.

(Like Slock.it should for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Some propose a hardware wallet: https://www.ledgerwallet.com/products/12-ledger-nano-s

Also you won't find anything today about mining except graphic card used to GPU mine. No Asics are available as they would cost more than just a bunch of AMD cards. You can find ready to use rigs, but it will still use GPU cards.

There is also no publicly available hardware that would enable to do what Ethereum computer was intended to do.

I think the reasons for that are the following. but please take this as my personal point of view and perhaps not reasons that most of the community agrees on.

- I guess slock.it and The DAO failure put a big stop on dedicated hardware. Slock.it was intended to develope the Ethereum computer using The DAO funding, but you probably know what happened to The DAO and so no Ethereum computer will be made by this team. Perhaps it made other teams think twice before getting in the hardware adventure.
- We don't need dedicated hardware to mine as mining is only valuable if you reuse old parts and GPU. Also future move to PoS will make all mining hardware unusable, so no hope to have ROI on a dedicated hardware development and production for now.
- Ethereum is still not in its stable phase. Metropolis is not there. So making hardware now would target only a few Ethereum enthusiasts but wouldn't be enough to go to mass market and would be obsolete in a few months even if you are able to update its software.
- mobile technology is widely available and mobile networks are more and more efficient. Comming soon light client will make any  mobile phone able to use the chain. So most end user use case will be possible without dedicated hardware.

I guess there are more cases to hit lack of dedicated hardware. But here is my small contribution.

Answer (score 1):

There are people selling their own builds on ebay.
http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR5.TRC2.A0.H0.Xethereum+mining+rig.TRS0&_nkw=ethereum+mining+rig&_sacat=0
Nearly all these builds use a "pro btc motherboard" with pci1x to pci16x raisers. But I would NOT recommend buying any of these because they are way overpriced and when ethereum finally switches to pos these rigs will be worthless!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like these guys plan to sell some kind of custom-made debit card. Not currently on sale though.

[Monolith](http://monolith.ventures/tokencard.html)